# Checking if an array contains two numbers

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, boolean

i have just started with Java and facing a problem right now, which i cannot solve after 2hrs of checking code.
When i input :
7 ( as length)
6 3 4 8 3 2 6 (as array)
8 3 (as numbers to check)

it Writes false, but clearly they are included in the exact order.
Please help me trying to understand what the problem is

here is the Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[length];

        boolean broken = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int j = 1; j < length; j++) {

            if (numbers[j] == n && numbers[j-1] == m || numbers[j] == m && numbers[j+1] == n || numbers[j] == m && numbers[j-1] == n || numbers[j] == n && numbers[j+1] == m) {
                broken = false;
            } else {
                broken = true;
            }

        }
        if (broken) {
            System.out.println("false");
        } else {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe should `break` out of the loop, once you found the pair?

Comment: You are not breaking out of the loop when it is true. You are checking until the end of the numbers array. 'break' out of the loop when the condition is true. Else it effectively is returning whether its broken at the last 2 indices of the array.

Comment: Your Solutions have worked for the example i have mentioned, but when it checks different numbers ( 3 for length; 2 1 2 for array; 2 3 for check numbers) it gives me an out of bound error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in a comment, you want to check on {n,m} and {m,n} so why do you have more conditions?
The following is enough:

```
for (int j = 0; j < length-1; j++) {
    if (numbers[j] == n && numbers[j+1] == m || numbers[j] == m && numbers[j+1] == n) {
        broken = false;
        break;
    } else {
        broken = true;
    }
}
```

The loop goes from 0 (=first array element) to the last -1 because the if compares with j+1. Once you have found a match you have to break out of the loop otherwise you risk to set `broken` to false again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense now to keep it that short as it covers every condition to check,
but now i get the wrong output again with the example of
3 as length
1 3 2 as numbers
2 3 as numbers to check

Shouldnt it be covered by the condition?

Comment: If I test with your example it prints true. Which is the correct answer I think.

Comment: Okay i got it running now and it works fine, i have never heard of setting the length of an array to " -1 ", but it now makes sense for me!
Thanks alot!

Comment: Just for clarity: I don't set the length to -1. I let j iterate from 0 to one less than the length because within the for loop I use index j+1 which would generate an out of bound exception if j would go up to length.

Comment: Yes, i have just answered incomprehensible. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this without using a boolean, check tweaked code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class checker {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int howManyValuesPresent = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Length of array");
    int length = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }


    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    int m = scanner.nextInt();


    for(int number: numbers){
        if(number == n || number == m){
            howManyValuesPresent++;
        }
    }

    if (howManyValuesPresent>0) {
        System.out.println("true, Your selected numbers appear: " + howManyValuesPresent + " times in array");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false, Your selected numbers appear: " + howManyValuesPresent + " times in array");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as a beginner i am trying to stick to the stuff i already know like booleans!